# Xcode crashes when clicking at SKS files

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I had `Xcode 7.3` and, every time I click the `.sks` file, the same problem happens - **Xcode crashes**. I even try to right click the `sks` file and choose Open In Sprite Kit Editor. But it still crashes.

And I tried installing Xcode 7.3.1 Beta, but it STILL crashes when I click the sks file.

I know that there are other people having the same problem, and have asked on this site, but there is still NO proper answer to solve it. 
:(

Please help me if you know any possible solution. The sks file is so convenient when designing games. If I can use it, it will save much of my effort.